# Need proprietary Nvidia drivers not in stable Debian

Tags: debian, drivers, nvidia, proprietary-drivers, bumblebee

I need to install proprietary Nvidia drivers in my Debian Wheezy (to use CUDA if you wonder why) but none of these two options work for me:

1. From Wheezy (backports) packages, the last nvidia-driver version is [319.82](https://packages.debian.org/wheezy-backports/nvidia-driver) and it does not manage my graphic card which is recent enough (GTX850M).
2. From Nvidia website (using .run file), I can get the very last version of the driver, compatible with my card, but it breaks my system because -- as I guess -- I need [Bumblebee](https://packages.debian.org/wheezy-backports/bumblebee)... which refuses to be installed if Nvidia drivers were installed using .run file!

What is the solution except waiting for drivers upgrade in Debian?

Hint: it seems sid [nivida-driver](https://packages.debian.org/sid/nvidia-driver) may solve my problem, but I am afraid that if I start using sid packages, because of nvidia-driver and bumblebee dependencies, I will need to cope with a stable/sid packages mixture for a while...

Comment: Have you considered running another distribution like Ubuntu? I mean, I'm a big fan of Debian, but I don't think that Debian stable is the first choice when it comes to non-free driver support for recent hardware...

Comment: Actually, I never succeeded in setting up Debian Wheezy on my Laptop and I am using Linux Mint Debian instead. It is based on Debian backports if I am not making a mistake. I seriously considered ArchLinux but lack time to properly manage a PC under such a distribution and I am not a big fan of Ubuntu (for irrational reasons maybe...). I am not familiar enough with other distributions and now that (almost) everything is configured and running on my computer...

Comment: May be you should upgrade your whole system to sid, since having mix of different packages may brake your system.

Comment: IMO Ubuntu is perfect if you want Debian with support for non-free drivers and recent software. I'd go with that.

Comment: I already mentioned that Ubuntu is not my favorite Linux distribution but it's even worse: the latest [nividia driver](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty-updates/nvidia-331) for Ubuntu [does not include](http://www.nvidia.com/download/driverResults.aspx/72250/en-us) my graphic card...

Comment: In your situation, getting the latest source package and compiling is probably the easiest solution. Note that you generally need matching kernel and Xorg drivers.

Comment: @Gilles Is it possible to compile a proprietary driver? I admit I've never looked inside a proprietary source package... And what do you mean by "you need matching kernel and Xorg drivers"?

Answer (score 2):

The latest nvidia drivers are in debian `experimental`.  You can add that to your sources.list, like so:

```
deb http://your.nearest.mirror/debian experimental main contrib non-free
```

You also have to add `APT::Default-Release "stable";` to `/etc/apt/apt.conf` to ensure that you don't get packages from `experimental` unless you explicitly add `-t experimental` to the apt-get command line.

To install the latest nvidia packages, you'd run:

```
apt-get -t experimental install nvidia-driver xserver-xorg-video-nvidia ...
```

There are numerous related packages to install, and the exact package names will change over time.  I wrote the following script `list-nvidia.sh` to help keep them upgraded...it lists all currently installed or held nvidia-related packages.

```
#! /bin/bash

PKGS=$(dpkg -l '*nvidia*' '*cuda*' '*vdpau*' 2>/dev/null| awk '/^[hi]i/ {print $2}')

if [ "$1" == "-v" ] ; then 
  dpkg -l $PKGS
else
  echo "$PKGS"
fi
```

I use it like this:

```
apt-get -t experimental install $(list-nvidia.sh)
```

Occasionally, packages get renamed or obsoleted so they have to be excluded from the install list like this:

```
apt-get -t experimental install $(list-nvidia.sh | egrep -v 'nvidia-cuda-mps|nvidia-smi')
```

And, of course, you can add as many other package names as you like to the end of that `apt-get` command line (but they will all come from `experimental`, not `stable` because that's what you're telling `apt-get` to do).

Comment: BTW, the `-t experimental` option also works with `aptitude` and other `apt` tools.

Comment: and finally, my answer above is easily adapted to cater for `sid` as well as (or instead of) `experimental`.  You can add an unstable line to your sources.list and as long as you have the Default-release line in apt.conf, you won't get sid packages unless you specify `-t unstable`.  I've found that `unstable` can be weeks or months behind `experimental` for nvidia packages.

Answer (score 0):

Crunchbang distribution is based on Wheezy and has been rock stable. I chose it after trying Ubuntu, Mint, Debian testing. In fact I reinstalled all my machines to use crunchbang. The only let down has been the trying to get NVidia to work. I finally used smxi script to do it. Fantastic. Crunchbang uses openbox, it is sleek, smooth, fast and complete. A right balance between geeky and beginner desktop. Strongly recommend.